# Merging keys on a dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I want to use the minimun cuts algorithm in a python's graph such that:

```
 { 1 : [5, 8, 10], 2 :[3, 8, 9] } == { 1 : [5, 8, 10, 3, 9] }
```

What is the more pythonic way of merging the dictionaries?

Comment: Why are the two lists values of a dictionary?

Comment: @jojo It's for testing against the input from a textfile and I found it easier than using the Graph function

Comment: When you consider to use one of the answers, I would also consider using sets from the start, instead of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set.union` to get the unique values then convert it to set and get the minimum key with `min` function :

```
>>> {min(d.keys()):list(set().union(*d.values()))}
{1: [8, 9, 10, 3, 5]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `import operator` then `reduce` the dictionary `values` by adding them to one another like so

```
set(reduce(operator.add, d.values())) # the set of each successive value added to the next
```

Comment: Have you printed this? You'll need to call `set` on your output.

Comment: @jojo OP never said he wanted to remove duplicates.

Comment: Not explicitly, but if you look closely at the question the desired output removes duplicates.

Comment: @jojo Corrected, didn't notice the 8 there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two lists:

```
a = [5, 8, 10]
b = [3, 8, 9]
```

You can merge them with minimum cut policy like so:

```
list(set(b) | set(a))
```

If you want to do the operation in place, use:

```
a[:] = list(set(b) | set(a))
```

Comment: why not `list(set(a) | set(b))`?

Comment: @WorldSEnder try! Hint: `+` operator might not be defined for `set`.

Comment: Silly me, `|` - sure thing!

Comment: @jojo what does `|` do? is it like a regex `|`  thats basically like an `or`?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez with two sets `a | b == a.union(b)`